# Set self as delegate when Initializing a property with a closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures, core-location

In my code I created a CLLocationManager property in my class.
I wanted to use a closure for initializing the location manager because I would be able to set the delegate right there, and I think it's awesome to configure the properties on their declarations (as I used to do in Objective C on the property getter).

So I tried this:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    var lm = CLLocationManager()
    lm.delegate = self
    return lm
}()

extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
}
```

But I am receiving the following error on the lm.delegate = self line.

> /Users/.../MapViewController.swift:18:23: Cannot assign
>   value of type 'NSObject -> () -> MapViewController' to type
>   'CLLocationManagerDelegate?'

MapViewController conforms to the delegate (because of the extension below), so I don't think "nonconfirmity" is the issue.

I could initialise the delegate on viewDidLoad, I know, but if it's possible to initialize on the property itself I would really like to learn to do it because it feels so neat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, I just found the answer:

```
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = { [unowned self] in
    var lm = CLLocationManager()
    lm.delegate = self
    return lm
}()
```

Got it from this cool article about lazy initialization in Swift by Mike Buss:
http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/

Comment: There is no need to use [unowned self]. The reason is that the immediately applied closure {}() is considered @noescape. It does not retain the captured self.

Comment: Since Swift 3.x closure became @nonescaping by default.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stack with an error

```
Cannot assign value of type '(Foo) -> () -> Foo' to type 'Bar'
```

In my case it was

```
Cannot assign value of type '(AppDelegate) -> () -> AppDelegate' to type ...
```

Please, check that you use it for **lazy** variables. I spent a few minutes until I observed that I'm trying lazy instantiation for a **let** constant.

For example,

```
let foo: Foo = { ... }
```

instead should be

```
lazy var foo: Foo = { ... }
```